# returns names but fails to count first examples

Tags: python

This code is supposed to return the first names form the data and the return the first name and how many #times a particular name exists.

It works fine but David, the first name, comes out as David 1 David 1 , when it obviously should be # #David 2!!!!

```
def name_counts(name):

    name = str(name)

    name = name.split()

    wordDictionary = {}

    for word in name[::2]:

       if word in wordDictionary:

            wordDictionary[word] += 1

       else:
            wordDictionary[word] = 1

    return wordDictionary

name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
print(name_counts(name_list))
```

Comment: `name` is already a list when `name_counts` is called; don't try to split the string representation of the list if all you want is to count first names.

Comment: To get a list of just first names, use `first_names = [name.split()[0] for name in name_list]`, instead of the awkward back and forth between a list and string as you're doing now. That'll make things a lot easier.

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) should be helpful here.

Comment: The first element of `str(name_list).split()` is `"['David"`, not `"David"`. Further, all the names include a single quote introduced by the conversion to a `str`: `"'David"`, `"Joyner'"`, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add one line in your function and you will understand why all this happening.

```
print(name[0], name[2])
```

Add above line after line

```
name = str(name)
```

And run your code again.

Answer (score 2):

Split each element of the input list separately. Also, use `collections.Counter` to count the names.

```
import collections


def name_counts(names):
    d = collections.Counter()
    for name in names:
        first, last = name.split()
        d[first] += 1
    return d
```

This can be shortened to

```
def name_counts(names):
    return Counter(name.split()[0] for name in names)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your problem, but an alternative. Use at your own risk (as in: make sure you understand what it does):

```
from collections import Counter

name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
first_names = [name.split()[0] for name in name_list]
first_names_counts = Counter(first_names)
print(first_names_counts)
```

yields

```
Counter({'David': 2, 'Brenton': 2, 'Nicol': 1, 'Shelba': 5, 'Maren': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
name = str(name)
```

to:

```
name = ' '.join(name)
```

When a list is converted to string, it includes the commas and brackets.

Comment: Thanks Amal!!!!  As you may realise I'm at an early stage with Python!

Comment: Good luck with your Python journey. Be sure to upvote all helpful answers. :)